# Replacement phrase for "in that"

Tags: phrases

When writing I find myself using the phrase *"in that"* when tying together an opinion or point of debate. I am needing some alternative phrases that have the same meaning to spice up my writing. Any suggestions?

Example:

> The same can be said about Twinkies; in that over-consumption can lead
>   to obesity, cardiovascular disease, and diabetes.

Comment: You could use *insofar as*, but you really wouldn't want to repeat either of these very close together in your writing. Try writing *nothing at all*; I think you'll find it reads just as fluently, if not better. Or recast the sentence so it starts with *Overconsumption of Twinkies can* **also** *lead to obesity,...*.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the semicolon in your instance should be replaced by a comma; merely leaving the semicolon and removing "in that" could be just as effective.

Comment: @zpletan: There is no hard-and-fast rule in play here. Increasingly the modern tendency is to use a comma where in the past it would have been a semicolon. But in OP's example you probably *wouldn't*, simply because that clashes with two more commas later in the sentence which are being used in a different way.

Comment: I think *as* is the most innocuous option, but @zpletan is right that the semicolon needs to be a comma.

Answer (score 3):

A colon seems a good alternative (though a little more context to the sentence would better help me understand:

```
The same can be said about Twinkies: over-consumption can lead to
obesity, cardiovascular disease, and diabetes.
```

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't just leave OP's original *semicolon* unchanged, while discarding his *in that*. A full-on *colon* seems ott to me.

Comment: Partly because I am a serial abuser of the colon, and with all this talk of tasty Twinkies treats, I am thinking about abusing my other colon too. However, the OP's goal it to make a causative link between the two clauses: the reason the same can be said about Twinkies is because of all that over-consumption. A semicolon seems a little too weak since the causative link is so strong. However, I am guessing a little at the context of the sentence, and if I guess wrong, you might be right.

Comment: A semicolon is the correct punctuation to use here. In fact, it would be grammatically correct to just admit "in that" altogether, with the semicolon already there!

Comment: @Noldorin: I think you meant *omit*, not *admit*. Certainly that's what I meant in my original comment when I said replace *in that* with *nothing at all*.

Comment: I’m all for the colon here: in the words of R L Trask in ‘The Penguin Guide to Punctuation’, ‘the colon is used to indicate that what follows it is an explanation or elaboration of what precedes it.’

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes indeed; I wrote this comment at 3:00am, so please forgive. :-) Didn't fully read your comment, for similar reason. Glad we agree on it though?

Comment: @Barrie: Only my opinion, but as I've said before, I think the general trend over recent decades is to reduce punctuation. Sometimes that means downgrading colons to semicolons, and semicolons to commas, as well as sometimes changing commas to *nothing at all*. It might be interesting to put OP's particular example up as a question in its own right: do people prefer it with a colon or semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, you could use *because*, *since*, or *as* for a one-word replacement.

Answer (score 0):

- *For the reason that...*
- *because...*

Found [here](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/in-that). Perhaps not exactly spicy.

Answer (score 0):

"As such" also works. "Insofar as" and semicolons are good alternatives, as is the dash ( -- ).